# Simple regex on string

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a simple mention system and in my PHP script and I need to extract `client:6` from the larger text where one or more @mention like `@[John Doe (#6)](client:6)` will be present.

Ex. `This is my text how do you like it @John and do you have any thoughts @Jane`

In php the string will look like.

```
This is my text how do you like it @[John Doe (#6)](client:6) and do you have any thoughts @[Jane Doe (#7)](client:7)
```

and i need to get an array with `array('client:6','client:7')`

Comment: Yes a lot on https://regex101.com/, but i don't know how it works so i'm just guessing and getting no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many possible ways would be

```
@\[[^][]+\]\s*\(\K[^()]+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/g6K6ef/1/).

---

In terms of regular expressions, this boils down to

```
@          # "@" literally
\[         # "[" literally
[^][]+     # not "[" nor "]" as many times as possible
\]\s*      # followed by "]" literally + whitespaces, eventually
\(         # you name it - "(" literally
\K         # forget all what has been matched that far
[^()]+     # not "(" nor ")"
```

---

In `PHP` this could be

```
<?php

$data = "This is my text how do you like it @[John Doe (#6)](client:6) and do you have any thoughts @[Jane Doe (#7)](client:7)";

$regex = "~@\[[^][]+\]\s*\(\K[^()]+~";

preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

And would yield

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => client:6
            [1] => client:7
        )

)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/1OBYnK).

Comment: This seems to be working nicely on your demo. I'll test it out.

Answer (score 1):

`\w+:\d+` should work.

In the sentence :

> This is my text how do you like it @John Doe (#6) and do
> you have any thoughts @Jane Doe (#7)

It should find client:6 and client:7 .

You can try your regex live using https://regexr.com/ for example.

Comment: Cool that works, but how to make it a bit better so it will only catch entries that begins with @. Just so it won't catch if i just write `client:10` with out writing `@[John Smith](client:10)`.

Comment: It could also be an idea to first get an array of all @ like `array('@[John Smith](client:10)',@[Jane Smith](client:12))` and loop through them to get the specific `client:10`